# Query operation in Mongodb to find left outer between two query from the same collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need help to find the left outer between two queries from the same collection.

Let just say i one collection with the below records:

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(1), 
    "clientId" : "1", 
    "requestId" : "100"
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(2),
    "clientId" : "2", 
    "requestId" : "100"
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(3), 
    "clientId" : "3", 
    "requestId" : "100"
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(4), 
    "clientId" : "4", 
    "requestId" : "100"
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(5), 
    "clientId" : "5", 
    "requestId" : "100"
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(6), 
    "clientId" : "6", 
    "requestId" : "100"
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(7), 
    "clientId" : "7", 
    "requestId" : "100"
}

{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(8), 
    "clientId" : "6", 
    "requestId" : "200"
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(9), 
    "clientId" : "7", 
    "requestId" : "200"
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(10), 
    "clientId" : "8", 
    "requestId" : "200"
}
```

I get one request with two fields, the first one is "mainRequestId" and other "excludedRequestId". I need to find to records which client Ids have "mainRequestId" but not in "excludedRequestId".

For Example: "mainRequestId" = "100", "excludedRequestId" = "200", I should get following records:

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(1), 
    "clientId" : "1", 
    "requestId" : "100"
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(2),
    "clientId" : "2", 
    "requestId" : "100"
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(3), 
    "clientId" : "3", 
    "requestId" : "100"
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(4), 
    "clientId" : "4", 
    "requestId" : "100"
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(5), 
    "clientId" : "5", 
    "requestId" : "100"
}
```

Because `clientId` 6 and 7 has `requestId` "100" but have another record with client Id 6 and 7 but also `requestId` "200".

How can i do this with mongo query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try aggregation pipeline query,

- `$match` to check `requestId` is equal to `mainRequestId`
- `$lookup` to join self collection

  - `$match` `clientId` and `requestId` with `excludedRequestId`
  - `$limit` to return only one document
- `$match` check return result from document is empty []

```
let mainRequestId = "100";
let excludedRequestId = "200";

db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { requestId: mainRequestId } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      let: { clientId: "$clientId" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $and: [
              { $expr: { $eq: ["$$clientId", "$clientId"] } },
              { requestId: excludedRequestId }
            ]
          }
        },
        { $limit: 1 }
      ],
      as: "hasDoc"
    }
  },
  { $match: { hasDoc: [] } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PLlVLvhP6Ac)

Comment: When Collection has a lots of records, like 150k records with mainRequestId=100 and 100k records excludedRequestId=200, After wait a long time I get "Database error (MongoExecutionTimeoutException): Error in $cursor stage :: caused by :: operation exceeded time limit"

Comment: You need to create a single index on `requesId` and `clientId`, and also a compound index for both the fields. otherwise, if you select all records at once definitely it will exceed the time limit, or implement pagination.

Comment: With Your suggestion, I have solved my problem. But some cases When mainRequestId =3M and excludedRequestId=2M I just want to know just count of this query. With This query takes more than 4-5 minutes. Is there any way to faster it. Thanks.